# React hooks & Context: Error when using context inside a child component with useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I've created a `react` function component for the context as follows:

`const ItemContext = createContext()`

```
const ItemProvider = (props) => {
    const [item, setItem] = useState(null)

    const findById = (args = {}) => {
        fetch('http://....', { method: 'POST' })
          .then((newItem) => {
            setItem(newItem)
          })
    }

    let value = {
        actions: {
            findById
        },
        state: {
            item
        }
    }

    return <ItemContext.Provider value={value}>
        {props.children}
    </ItemContext.Provider>
}
```

In this way, I have my context that handles all the API calls and stores the state for that `item`. (Similar to `redux` and others)

Then in my child component further down the line that uses the above context...

```
const smallComponent = () =>{
    const {id } = useParams()
    const itemContext = useContext(ItemContext)

    useEffect(()=>{
        itemContext.actions.findById(id)
    },[id])

    return <div>info here</div>
}
```

So the component should do an API call on change of `id`. But I'm getting this error in the console:

> React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'itemContext.actions'. Either include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

If I add it in the dependency array though, I get a never ending loop of API calls on my server. So I'm not sure what to do. Or if I'm going at this the wrong way. Thanks.

=== UPDATE ====
Here is a jsfiddle to try it out: https://jsfiddle.net/zx5t76w2/
(FYI I realized the warning is not in the console as it's not linting)

Comment: The error in the console is caused by the eslint rule. You can either chose to disable the rule, or implement the useCallback option from the answer below

Comment: Feels like if there is an error/warning, it's not the right way of doing something, but it also seems weird that I would call an API in my component to update the context that then updates the component...(just moved from REDUX).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just utilize `useCallback` for your fetch method, which [returns a memoized function:](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback)

```
const findById = useCallback((args = {}) => {
  fetch("http://....", { method: "POST" }).then(newItem => {
    setItem(newItem);
  });
}, []);
```

...and put it in the `useEffect`:

```
...
const { actions, state } = useContext(ItemContext)

useEffect(() => {
    actions.findById(id)
}, [id, actions.findById])
...
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/6r5jx1h7/1/

Your problem is related to `useEffect` calling your custom hook again and again, because it's a normal function that React is not "saving" throughout the renders.

---

**UPDATE**

My initial answer fixed the infinite loop.
Your problem was also related to the way you use the context, as it recreates the domain objects of your context (`actions`, `state`, ..) again and again ([See caveats in the official documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#caveats)).

Here is your example in [Kent C. Dodds'](https://stackoverflow.com/users/971592/kentcdodds) wonderful way of splitting up context into `state` and `dispatch`, which I can't recommend enough. This will fix your infinite loop and provides a cleaner structure of the context usage. Note that I'm still using `useCallback` for the fetch function based on my original answer:

Complete Codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/fancy-sea-bw70b

> App.js

```
import React, { useEffect, useCallback } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import { useItemState, ItemProvider, useItemDispatch } from "./item-context";

const SmallComponent = () => {
  const id = 5;
  const { username } = useItemState();
  const dispatch = useItemDispatch();

  const fetchUsername = useCallback(async () => {
    const response = await fetch(
      "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/" + id
    );
    const user = await response.json();
    dispatch({ type: "setUsername", usernameUpdated: user.name });
  }, [dispatch]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchUsername();
  }, [fetchUsername]);

  return (
    <div>
      <h4>Username from fetch:</h4>
      <p>{username || "not set"}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ItemProvider>
        <SmallComponent />
      </ItemProvider>
    </div>
  );
}
```

> item-context.js

```
import React from "react";

const ItemStateContext = React.createContext();
const ItemDispatchContext = React.createContext();

function itemReducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "setUsername": {
      return { ...state, username: action.usernameUpdated };
    }
    default: {
      throw new Error(`Unhandled action type: ${action.type}`);
    }
  }
}

function ItemProvider({ children }) {
  const [state, dispatch] = React.useReducer(itemReducer, {
    username: "initial username"
  });
  return (
    <ItemStateContext.Provider value={state}>
      <ItemDispatchContext.Provider value={dispatch}>
        {children}
      </ItemDispatchContext.Provider>
    </ItemStateContext.Provider>
  );
}

function useItemState() {
  const context = React.useContext(ItemStateContext);
  if (context === undefined) {
    throw new Error("useItemState must be used within a CountProvider");
  }
  return context;
}

function useItemDispatch() {
  const context = React.useContext(ItemDispatchContext);
  if (context === undefined) {
    throw new Error("useItemDispatch must be used within a CountProvider");
  }
  return context;
}

export { ItemProvider, useItemState, useItemDispatch };
```

Both of these blog posts helped me a lot when I started using context with hooks initially:

https://kentcdodds.com/blog/application-state-management-with-react
https://kentcdodds.com/blog/how-to-use-react-context-effectively

Comment: Your answer misses the part that itemContext.actions.findById should be put into the deps, if you put itemContext.actions, it will still get in a loop as a new objects is  created every time thus itemContext.actions reference will change

Comment: I tried to add the `useCallback` in my `ItemProvider` but it didn't solve it. I then tried to create a new function in my child component that is wrapped around `useCallback` but now the error is showing up in for that new function instead of `use effect`

Comment: I've created a jsfiddle to show the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/ctw9Lod1/

Comment: @BennettDams Thanks for the deep update. The reason I was trying to do it this way was to avoid having my API calls and any kind of business logic in my "smaller" components. If I have to refactor an API endpoint, or have to append an auth token...would need to do it in all the components...is there any way I can have my API fetches done somewhere in the `context`?

Comment: A little like in `redux` and `redux-thunk` it would be in my `actions` file.

Comment: I had a play with it here: https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-cerf-vuodx?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @denislexic I wouldn't do this in the contexts of the components, rather create a custom hook to fetch from the API. Then use that custom hooks in the components itself. They could also dispatch that response to their context. For this topic I can highly recommend "React Query":  https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-query

Comment: @BennettDams Thanks for the help! Seeing that you are an expert, I ran into another issue posted here if you want more points: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61215193/react-hooks-dependencies-including-it-creates-an-infinite-loop-not-including-i

Answer (score 0):

OK, I didn't want to write an answer as Bennett basically gave you the fix, but I think it is missing the part in the component, so here you go:

```
const ItemProvider = ({ children }) => {
   const [item, setItem] = useState(null)

   const findById = useCallback((args = {}) => {
      fetch('http://....', { method: 'POST' }).then((newItem) => setItem(newItem))
   }, []);

   return (
      <ItemContext.Provider value={{ actions: { findById }, state: { item } }}>
         {children}
      </ItemContext.Provider>
   )
}

const smallComponent = () => {
   const { id } = useParams()
   const { actions } = useContext(ItemContext)

   useEffect(() => {
     itemContext.actions.findById(id)
   }, [actions.findById, id])

   return <div>info here</div>
}
```

Extended from the comments, here's the working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1vLgz3rq/)

Comment: Thanks for the elaboration. It seems to still be going into a loop this way. See fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/ctw9Lod1/ (Look at console for loop)

Comment: The jsfiddle you provided is not the same as the code I've posted. You have two issues: 1)  useCallback is missing the second argument [] and 2) you have 
[id, itemContext.actions], in my answer I said to change it to: 
[id, itemContext.actions.findById]

Comment: Thanks for the update. Unfortunately, the warning is for the missing `actions` dependency and not the `actions.findById`. And if I put `actions` as a dependency, I get an infinite loop.

Comment: I had a similar issue. You should only have primitive types or callbacks as dependencies, no objects. When you put `const {findById} = actions.findById` and then set `findById` as dependency, does the infinite loop go away?