# React hooks dependencies, including it creates an infinite loop, not including it doesn't give me the latest value

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Using `React hooks`. 
I'm trying to do a simple API fetch call with some data, but I can't seem to make this work. 
Here is the [sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-bose-zuwti?file=/src/App.js)

In this example, the objective is that every 5secs, it fetches to the server to get any updates to the username since the latest `latestUpdate`.

But for convenience, I will include the code here as well:

```
const SmallComponent = () => {
  const { id, username, latestUpdate } = useItemState();
  const dispatch = useItemDispatch();

  console.log("Render id", id, "Latest", latestUpdate);

  const fetchUsername = useCallback(async () => {
    console.log("Getting Id", id, "Latest", latestUpdate);
    const response = await fetch(
      "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/" + id
    );
    const user = await response.json();
    dispatch({ type: "setUsername", usernameUpdated: user.name });
  }, [dispatch, id]);

  const updateId = useCallback(() => {
    dispatch({ type: "setId", id: id + 1 });
  }, [dispatch, id]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchUsername();
    const refresh = setInterval(() => {
      updateId();
    }, 5000);

    return () => clearInterval(refresh);
  }, [fetchUsername, updateId]);

  return (
    <div>
      <h4>Username from fetch:</h4>
      <p>{username || "not set"}</p>
    </div>
  );
};
```

As you'll notice, my `fetchUsername` is missing a dependency for `latestUpdate` (which is used on my server to only send udpates since that date). I update latestUpdate when the `fetchUsername` is finished in my reducer.

What I need:

- on mount: fetch username => updates state for username and latestUpdate
- interval: every 5secs => fetch updates to username and update latestUpdate to `new Date()`

The problem is:

- If I add the dependency to the `useCallback` for `fetchUsername`, I get an infinite refresh loop.
- If I don't add it, my `latestUpdate` value is wrong (ie initial value)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It would help other readers if you explained the expected behavior, it's not immediately clear from the code. In particular, the need for `useCallback` and `setInterval` and your choice of dependencies are difficult to understand.

Comment: @slezica Ok, hopefully I cleared up the `setInterval` (its a data refresh from server). As for the `useCallback`, I was hoping it would, when called upon, use the latest data without including it in the dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're not using the fetch method anywhere else, it makes sense to put it inside the `useEffect` directly. No need for `useCallback`:

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchUsername = async () => {
      console.log("FETCH", latestUpdate);
      const url =
        "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/" + id + "#" + latestUpdate;

      const response = await fetch(url);
      const user = await response.json();
      dispatch({ type: "setUsername", usernameUpdated: user.name });
    };

    const refresh = setInterval(() => {
      fetchUsername();
    }, 5000);

    return () => clearInterval(refresh);
  }, [dispatch, id, latestUpdate]);
```

Here is the full CodeSandBox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-framework-hvw06?file=/src/App.js

You can find more in the official docs (look for "...*to move that function inside of your effect*"): 
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-it-safe-to-omit-functions-from-the-list-of-dependencies

And I also recommend Robin Wieruch's hook-fetching tutorial: https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-hooks-fetch-data

In general, I would highly recommend using something like `react-query`, as it will also take care of caching. It is a better way to consume your server data (instead of fetching and putting the response in your context): https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-query